# How to get the numeric value of an integral using sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy, integral

I'm trying to use this function

```
def mean(f):
    r=sym.integrate(f,(t,0,0.02))
    return r
```

where `f` is

```
    f1=t
    x=t
    x=sym.sin(2*pi*50*t)
    f1=sym.sign(x)
```

And `t` is:

```
t=Symbol('t')
```

When I run the program I get this:

```
Integral(Piecewise((1, sin(314.159265358979*t) > 0), (-1, sin(314.159265358979*t) < 0), (0, True)), (t, 0, 0.02))
```

Is there a way to get the numeric answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because you are using `pi` from a numerical package (I guess `math` or `numpy`). When using symbolic expressions, you should use `pi` exposed by Sympy.

```
import sympy as sym

def mean(f):
    r=sym.integrate(f,(t,0,0.02))
    return r

t=Symbol('t')
x=sym.sin(2*sym.pi*50*t)
f1=sym.sign(x)
mean(f1)
# output: 0
```